# Argon design not rendering in laravel. How to extract it from node modules using mix?

Tags: laravel, argon

I have installed argon design system using npm. And inside the head tag, I have added links from the documentation. But I want to extract it from node modules using mix. And run in webpack so that it renders styles. Please, someone, help with a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

import the argon js file (in bootstrap.js for example if you're using the default laravel boilerplate) after popper, jquery and bootstrap:

```
require("argon-design-system-free/assets/js/argon-design-system");
```

and the css file (in app.scss if you're using it):

```
@import "~argon-design-system-free/assets/css/argon-design-system.css";
```

if you want the nucleo icons import then before the css file:

```
@import "~argon-design-system-free/assets/css/nucleo-icons.css";
```

Comment: Sir also what changes in links and scripts of argon href?